# Man looking at his face in a mirror

Tags: james

In James 1:23-24

> 23 For if anyone is a hearer of the word and not a doer, he is like a **man** who looks at his natural face in a mirror; 24 for once he has looked at himself and gone away, he has immediately forgotten what kind of person he was.

Is the word "man" here meaning "male"? That'd be curious in light that looking at the mirror and forgetting what was wrong isn't something I see happening as oft to women than to men...

Comment: remember to make the title specific and clear; add the phrase quote with verse ref.

Comment: @Michael16 isn't that personal preference?

Comment: It maybe, but you should anyway try to be clear and specific in the title, it will only help attract viewers, otherwise it is vague, clickbait, uninteresting. I dont know about rules but there should be rules about this.

Comment: @Michael16 I share a different view in there and would do that out of faith. So unless there was a strict rule enforcing it, don't see really the point... Try asking here on Meta first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James 1:23
English Standard Version

> For if anyone is a hearer of the word and not a doer, he is like a **man** [G435] who looks intently at his natural face in a mirror.

Thayer's Greek Lexicon
STRONGS NT 435: ἀνήρ

> 1. with a reference to sex, and so to distinguish a **man** from a woman; ...
> 2. with a reference to age, and to distinguish an adult **man** from a boy:

The same Greek word is used in Matthew 14:21

> And those who ate were about five thousand **men** [G435], besides women and children.

Is the word "man" here meaning "male"?

Yes, literally it is. However, the lesson is applied to both men and women.

> 25 But **whoever** looks intently into the perfect law that gives freedom, and continues in it—not forgetting what they have heard, but doing it—they will be blessed in what they do.

The point is that whoever you are, look deeper. Change your way of behavior to be consistent with the perfect law of Christ.